# Converting Pinescript Script from V1 to V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I Need help converting a script from V1 to V5. I keep getting many errors no matter what I try. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. The code is below

```
`strategy(title="ATR Strategy", overlay = true,  commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,commission_value=0.075)
nATRPeriod = input(2)
nATRMultip = input(3.5)
xATR = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
                    iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                        iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))
pos =   iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
        iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue 
plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color, title="ATR Trailing Stop")

barbuy = close > xATRTrailingStop 
barsell = close < xATRTrailingStop 

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = barbuy) 
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = barsell) 

barcolor(barbuy? green:red)`
```

I have tried converting it manually but I get too many errors as the gap between v1 and v5 is large.

Comment: What have you tried? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I have added //@version=5 to the top of the script and tried to compile whereby I receive the following error:  Compilation error. Line 8: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: You can't go from v1 to v5 directly. Increase the version one by one.

Comment: This error was trying to go to V2 or even V3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted

```
strategy(title='ATR Strategy', overlay=true, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075)
nATRPeriod = input(2)
nATRMultip = input(3.5)
xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
pos = 0.
xATR = ta.atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR
iff_1 = close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? close - nLoss : close + nLoss
iff_2 = close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss) : iff_1
xATRTrailingStop := close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss) : iff_2

iff_3 = close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)
pos := close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? 1 : iff_3

color_1 = pos == -1 ? color.red : pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color_1, title='ATR Trailing Stop')

barbuy = close > xATRTrailingStop
barsell = close < xATRTrailingStop

if barbuy
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)

if barsell
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)

barcolor(barbuy ? color.green : color.red)
```